# Placing label before radio button with JSF

Tags: jsf, label

i have the following in my page.

```
<h:selectOneRadio layout="pageDirection" >
     <s:selectItems value="#{usageList}" var="entry" 
      label="#{labels[entry.label]}" itemValue="entry" />
</h:selectOneRadio>
```

With this code I get a radio Button and after it the label of the same.

[ ] User

[ ] Administrator

But I want to do the following.

User [ ]

Administrator [ ]

Is it possible to do that with that using selectItems and selectOneRadio, or should I create the entries one by one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it is not a language matter (for which the `dir="rtl"` as mentioned in McDowell's (currently deleted?) post would not have been appropriate as it has more side-effects), then you can also just use CSS for this. It's good to know that the `<h:selectOneRadio>` renders a table with buttons and labels in the same cell. This way you could just let the button `float` to the `right` and also `align` the cell's `text` (the label) to `right`.

Basic CSS example:

```
.radioright td {
    text-align: right;
}
.radioright td input {
    float: right;
}
```

Apply `styleClass="radioright"` on the `<h:selectOneRadio>` and you'll be fine.

Comment: Thanks, I was thinking of using css but using the absolute property and setting the positioning. 

This solution is much better.